# card box across full screen width - bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

How can I adjust my 'card' so that it is displayed across the entire width of the screen? 
I am using bootstrap

```html
<div class="card">
     
  <h4 style="margin-top: 5px; width: 100%;">{{$tipo->tipo }}</h4> 
  
  </div>
```

[image]

**i need width similar to footer**

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the latest Bootstrap 4 then this code will create a card across the entire width:

```
<div class="card w-100 mt-2">
    <h4>Restaurante</h4> 
</div>
```

If there is still a gap then it is likely you have padding on the container div surrounding the card, so you would need to remove that.

Comment: Should I remove all the containers, do I remove the label or do I use CSS?

Comment: Which label? You would need to post the rest of your code for me to see what should change

Answer (score 0):

the first thing you need to notice it's that `card` class `display` is `flex` in bootstrap.Also `card-body` has a `20px` padding.So the first thing you need is use `p-0` in `card-body` then devide your card body to multi row.So you below code:

```
<div class='card'>
   <div class='card-img-top'>
     <img src='...' />
   </div>
   <div class='card-body p-0'>
     <div class='row mx-0'>
        <div class='col-12 p-2'>
          ...card content
        </div> 
     </div>
     <div class='d-block px-0'>
       <h4>Your footer</h4>
     </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

if you put a clear image to view what you want,I will help you more.I hope I could help you.